# Error: permission denied to access property "apply" - cross domain ASP.NET web service access through jquery

Tags: jquery, web-services

#### 1. Application Jquery -

---

```js
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://myurl.com/count.ashx?a=1",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",

    success: function(data) {
      debugger;

      $.each(data, function(index, value) {
        debugger;
        $("#mcount").text(value.InvestmentPraposalCount);

      });
    },
    error: function(xhr, status) {
      debugger;
      console.log(status);
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });

  function callbackFunc(resultData) {
    alert(resultData);
  }
});
```

#### 2. Web Service Response Data-

---

```
[{ "InvestmentPraposalCount" : "0", "HostingIncubatorProposalCount" : "2", "StartupEnrollmentCount" : "7", "Totals" : "9"}]
```

when i try to get and set data in our application url from service hosted at another location... it gives me error

> Error: Permission denied to access property "apply"
>   and parseerror.

What I have tried:

i have tried doing it in jsonp and crossdomain work in ajax request and also done changes in `web.config` of application for request and response headers. but all does not work..

Kindly help me out.

Comment: Your response data is not `jsonp`....!

Comment: can you help me out ? how it can done ?